# Coldfusion Optimizing a nested loop

Tags: arrays, loops, coldfusion, cfloop

I have a loop within a loop leading to longer loading time of my page. With more data the loading time can go up to 10,000 ms, which is about 10 seconds. How can I write it for faster load time? The code I have so far:

```
            <cfloop from="#endDate#" to="#startDate#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(+1,0,0,0)#"> 

                <cfset loopdate = dateformat(i,'mmm dd')>

                <!---Loop the number of likes for each day--->
                <cfset daylike = 0>
                <cfset dayretweet = 0>
                <cfset tweetrec = now()>

                <cfloop from = 1 to = #arraylen(DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent))# index = "i">      
                    <cfset tweetrec = dateformat(DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent)[i].created_at,'mmm dd')>
                    <cfif tweetrec IS loopdate>
                        <cfset daylike = daylike + DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent)[i].favorite_count>
                        <cfset dayretweet = dayretweet + DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent)[i].retweet_count>
                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>

                <!---add the favourites to array--->
                <cfset myarray = ArrayAppend(likes, "#daylike#")>

                <!--- Append dates to dates array  --->
                <cfset myarray = ArrayAppend(dates, "#loopdate#")>

                <!---Append retweets to retweets array --->
                <cfset myarray = ArrayAppend(retweetarr, "#dayretweet#")>
            </cfloop>
```

Comment: How often do the input variations change? Daily? If so don't do it inline on every request, but instead set up a scheduled task to run every `[period of change]` (eg: daily) to do the processing and put the resultant data in the application scope, or some cache or the like.

Comment: You have `DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent)` four times in your code. It would be much more efficient to do that once before the first loop starts and store it in a new variable. You're currently doing the same process multiple times on the same string which isn't required. Also noticed your inner and outer loops both have `index="i"` they should be different.

Comment: As John pointed out, the biggest gains will be to move `Deserialize` outside the loop, and then turn this into 1 loop instead of 2. You also assign the result of `ArrayAppend` (which is just a true/false) to a variable which is completely ignored. You may be able to save a few cycles by switching to `<cfset ArrayAppend(likes, "#daylike#")>`, but this will be minor in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code there are a few things you could do improve it.
You have `DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent)` four times in your code. It would be much more efficient to do that once before the first loop starts and store it in a new variable. You're currently doing the same process multiple times on the same string which isn't required. Also noticed your inner and outer loops both have `index="i"` they should be different.

Also as Adam said in the comments, if the data doesn't change very often then cache it / store it somewhere instead of re-calculating. A scheduled task would be good for this as the time it takes is not seen by the end user.

I think I'd probably look to refactor to only have one loop - so just loop over the dates that is in the returned JSON you are working with and make a new struct which contains the counts per day. So something like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="cfhttp.fileContent">[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "created_at": "1 January 2016",
            "favorite_count": 2,
            "retweet_count": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "created_at": "2 January 2016",
            "favorite_count": 4,
            "retweet_count": 20
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "created_at": "2 January 2016",
            "favorite_count": 7,
            "retweet_count": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "created_at": "2 January 2016",
            "favorite_count": 7,
            "retweet_count": 5
        }
]
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset data = DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.fileContent)>

<!--- convert data to get counts per day... --->
<cfset dataPerDay = {}>
<cfloop array="#data#" index="record">
    <!--- create a key which we can use to identity the date --->
    <cfset dateKey = DateFormat(record.created_at, "yyyymmdd")>
    <cfif structKeyExists(dataPerDay, dateKey)>
        <cfset dataPerDay[dateKey].favorite_count += record.favorite_count>
        <cfset dataPerDay[dateKey].retweet_count += record.retweet_count>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset dataPerDay[dateKey] = {
            favorite_count = record.favorite_count,
            retweet_count = record.retweet_count
        }>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#dataPerDay#">
```

Running that will produce a struct with two keys `20160101` and `20160102` which will have the cumulative count of favourites and retweets for that day.